# SQL isn't working as intended

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have an issue in my `SQL` query that I am trying to run (I am practicing at this point). I'm trying to get some registries between 2 specific dates and some conditionals.

The thing is, the query isn't working properly because it only shows the same registry all the time, I mean, if there is `100` entries the query shows `100` times the same entry.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT Base.Registry.Registry,
       Base.Client.Name,
       Base.Client.Surname1,
       Base.Client.Surname2,
       Base.Client.BirthDate,
       Base.Registry.Edad,
       Base.Client.NIF,
       Base.Registry.Procedency,
       Base.Registry.DateRegistry,
       Base.Registry.DateValidation,
       Base.Registry.CodeSample,
       Base.SnomedRegistry.Code,
       Base.Sample.T
FROM Base.Registry,
     Base.Client,
     Base.SnomedRegistry,
     Base.Sample
WHERE Base.Registry.CodeClient = Base.Client.CodeClient
  AND Base.Registry.Registry = Base.SnomedRegistry.Registry
  AND Base.Registry.CodeSample = Base.Sample.Sample
  AND Base.Registry.DateRegistry BETWEEN '2012-10-26' AND '2012-12-31'
  AND Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%3'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%2'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%6'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%9'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%2'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%3'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%6'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%9'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M69730'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M60760'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74000'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74007'
  OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74008'
  LIMIT 0, 100
```

I am quite inexperienced right now with SQL, so every advice would be appreciated.

Obs: Sorry for my english.

Comment: You need parentheses in the `where` to get the logic you want.  However, you should fix your query to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: **% matches any number of characters, even zero characters** so no need to add like `M8%%%2` or use `_`  which matches exactly one character like `M8___2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would comment rather than provide an answer, but I need 50 points to do that. lol

I'm not quite sure why you need to use % so many times like %%%%%, as usually one % is enough.

I would say your problem is to do with your from statement and ideally need to use joins.

I would also use brackets around your like statements...

```
WHERE   1 = 1 
    AND Base.Registry.CodeClient = Base.Client.CodeClient
    AND Base.Registry.Registry = Base.SnomedRegistry.Registry
    AND Base.Registry.CodeSample = Base.Sample.Sample
    AND Base.Registry.DateRegistry BETWEEN '2012-10-26' AND '2012-12-31'
    AND (
            Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%3'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%2'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%6'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%9'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%2'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%3'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%6'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%9'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M69730'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M60760'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74000'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74007'
            OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74008'
        )
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot parenthesis:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Base.Registry, Base.Client, Base.SnomedRegistry, Base.Sample
WHERE Base.Registry.CodeClient = Base.Client.CodeClient
AND Base.Registry.Registry = Base.SnomedRegistry.Registry
AND Base.Registry.CodeSample = Base.Sample.Sample
AND Base.Registry.DateRegistry
BETWEEN '2012-10-26' AND '2012-12-31'
AND (    #<----- here
   Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%3'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%2'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%6'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%9'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%2'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%3'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%6'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%9'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M69730'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M60760'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74000'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74007'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74008' 
)   #<----- here
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Answer (score 0):

with using `join` and parenthesis:

```
SELECT Base.Registry.Registry, Base.Client.Name, Base.Client.Surname1, Base.Client.Surname2, Base.Client.BirthDate, Base.Registry.Edad, Base.Client.NIF, Base.Registry.Procedency, Base.Registry.DateRegistry, Base.Registry.DateValidation, Base.Registry.CodeSample, Base.SnomedRegistry.Code, Base.Sample.T
FROM Base.Registry
inner join Base.Client on Base.Registry.CodeClient = Base.Client.CodeClient
inner join Base.SnomedRegistry on Base.Registry.Registry = Base.SnomedRegistry.Registry
inner join Base.Sample on Base.Registry.CodeSample = Base.Sample.Sample
WHERE Base.Registry.DateRegistry BETWEEN '2012-10-26' AND '2012-12-31'
AND (Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%3'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%2'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%6'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M8%%%9'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%2'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%3'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%6'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M9%%%9'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M69730'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M60760'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74000'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74007'
OR Base.SnomedRegistry.Code LIKE 'M74008')
LIMIT 0 , 100
```